Undefined reference but exists in the library
I have different .h in my code and they all follow the same structure and they work for me except a library in charge of reading and writing the data in .txt files, it gives me the error "undefined reference", I attach a test code with main where I try to execute the function of the library, the library and the .c where its functions are located
Error: undefined reference to iniciarClientesDeArchivo'`
main.c:
#include "Gestion_Fichero.h"

int main(){

    int p;
    Cliente *pruebas = iniciarClientesDeArchivo(&p);
    printf(p);

}

Gestion_Fichero.h:
#ifndef Gestion_Fichero_H
#define Gestion_Fichero_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "estructuras.h"

void guardarClientesEnArchivo(Cliente *clientes, int numClientes);
Cliente *iniciarClientesDeArchivo(int *numClientes);
void guardarAdminProvEnArchivo(AdminProv *admins, int numAdmins);
AdminProv *iniciarAdminProvDeArchivo(int *numAdmins);
void guardarProductosEnArchivo(Producto *productos, int numProductos);
Producto *iniciarProductosDeArchivo(int *numProductos);
void guardarCategoriasEnArchivo(Categoria *categorias, int numCategorias);
Categoria *iniciarCategoriasDeArchivo(int *numCat);
void guardarDescuentosEnArchivo(Descuento *descuentos, int numDescuentos);
Descuento *iniciarDescuentosDeArchivo(int *numDesc);
void guardarDescuentosClientesEnArchivo(DescuentoCliente *, int );
DescuentoCliente *iniciarDescuentosClientesDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarLockersEnArchivo(Locker *, int );
Locker *iniciarLockersDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarCompartimentoLockerEnArchivo(CompartimentoLocker *, int );
CompartimentoLocker *iniciarCompartimientoLockersDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarPedidoEnArchivo(Pedido *, int );
Pedido *iniciarPedidosDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarProductoPedidoEnArchivo(ProductoPedido *, int );
ProductoPedido *iniciarProductoPedidosDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarTransportistasEnArchivo(Transportista *, int );
Transportista *iniciarTransportistasDeArchivo(int *);
void guardarDevolucionesEnArchivo(Devolucion *, int );
Devolucion *iniciarDevolucionDeArchivo(int *);



#endif

Gestion_Fichero.c:
#include "Gestion_Fichero.h"

#define TAMANIO_MAXIMO_LINEA 256
#define Clientes_txt "Datos/Clientes.txt"
#define AdminProv_txt "Datos/AdminProv.txt"
#define Productos_txt "Datos/Productos.txt"
#define Categorias_txt "Datos/Categorias.txt"
#define Descuento_txt "Datos/Descuentos.txt"
#define DescuentoCliente_txt "Datos/DescuentosClientes.txt"
#define Lockers_txt "Datos/Lockers.txt"
#define CompartimentoLocker_txt "Datos/CompartimentosLockers.txt"
#define Pedido_txt "Datos/Pedidos.txt"
#define ProductoPedido_txt "Datos/ProductosPedidos.txt"
#define Transportistas_txt "Datos/Transportistas.txt"
#define Devoluciones_txt "Datos/Devoluciones.txt"

// Guarda el vector de clientes en el archivo siguiendo la estructura:
/*  o Identificador del cliente (Id_cliente), 7 digitos.
    o Nombre completo del cliente (Nomb_cliente), 20 caracteres maximo.
    o Dirección del cliente (Dir_cliente), 50 caracteres maximo.
    o Población (Localidad), 20 caracteres maximo.
    o Provincia (Provincia), 20 caracteres maximo.
    o Email (email), 30 caracteres maximo, sera usado como nombre de usuario para el acceso a la
    plataforma.
    o Contrasenia para acceder al sistema (Contrasenia), con 15 caracteres maximo.
    o Cartera (Cartera), almacenara el dinero del que dispone el cliente para poder adquirir los
    productos.
    */

void guardarClientesEnArchivo(Cliente *clientes, int numClientes)
{
    FILE *archivo = fopen(Clientes_txt, "w");
    if (archivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo %s.\n", Clientes_txt);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numClientes; i++)
    {
        fprintf(archivo, "%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%.2f\n",
                clientes[i].id_cliente,
                clientes[i].nomb_cliente,
                clientes[i].dir_cliente,
                clientes[i].localidad,
                clientes[i].provincia,
                clientes[i].email,
                clientes[i].contrasenia,
                clientes[i].cartera);
    }

    fclose(archivo);
}

// LE PASO COMO PUNTERO EL NUM DE CLIENTES PARA LUEGO PODER ALMACENARLO EN EL PROGRAMA (MAIN) -> MISMA LOGICA PARA LAS DEMAS LECTURAS
Cliente *iniciarClientesDeArchivo(int *numClientes)
{
    FILE *archivo = fopen(Clientes_txt, "r");
    if (archivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo %s.\n", Clientes_txt);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Contar la cantidad de lineas = clientes en el archivo
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[TAMANIO_MAXIMO_LINEA];
    while (fgets(buffer, TAMANIO_MAXIMO_LINEA, archivo) != NULL)
    {
        count++;
    }

    // Regresar al inicio del archivo
    rewind(archivo);

    // Crear vector cliente
    Cliente *clientes = (Cliente *)malloc(count * sizeof(Cliente));
    if (clientes == NULL)
    {
        fclose(archivo);
        printf("No se pudo asignar memoria para el vector de clientes.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Leer cada linea del archivo y rellenar el vector de clientes
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, TAMANIO_MAXIMO_LINEA, archivo) != NULL)
    {
        // Strtok sirve para dividir la cadena en subcadenas por "-"
        // - OS ADJUNTO DOCUMENTACION CONSULTADA: https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/i/7.5?topic=functions-strtok-tokenize-string
        // - VIDEO QUE LO EXPLICA CON SUMA: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHdbmHCVQ2c
        char *token = strtok(buffer, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].id_cliente, token, sizeof(clientes[i].id_cliente));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].nomb_cliente, token, sizeof(clientes[i].nomb_cliente));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].dir_cliente, token, sizeof(clientes[i].dir_cliente));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].localidad, token, sizeof(clientes[i].localidad));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].provincia, token, sizeof(clientes[i].provincia));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].email, token, sizeof(clientes[i].email));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strncpy(clientes[i].contrasenia, token, sizeof(clientes[i].contrasenia));
        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        clientes[i].cartera = atof(token); // atof convierte la cadena en Float.
        i++;
    }

    fclose(archivo);
    *numClientes = count;
    return clientes;
}

I have tried to gradually create the library and test the functions but it always fails, the compiler I use is gcc

If the duplicate doesn't help, [edit] your question with your exact compilation line.

It is a linker issue so you need to show you compile and link the program.
